Joint PDF: Finding the marginal

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0.5,  & \text{$|x|+|y| < 1$} \\
0, & \text{others}
\end{cases}$

Find the marginal of X

My attempt:
Here I assume that since it's absolute, then it should start from $0$ to $1-x$
$f(x) = \int_{0}^{1-x} 0.5\ dy$
$f(x) = \left.0.5y\right\rvert_{0}^{1-x}$
$f(x) = {1-x\over 2}$
Im not quite sure about the range of $X$. Is this correct?
Any help will do.

$f(x)=\int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|}0.5 dy$ for $|x|<1$.

Sketch $\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert <1$, which is a $\lozenge$ shape with vertices $(-1,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(0,1)$.  Notice the minimum and maximum values for $x$-ordinates in this shape.  Draw any vertical line through this shape, and identify the minimum and maximum values for $y$-ordinates on such a line segment (relative to the line's $x$-value).


Here I assume that since it's absolute, then it should start from $0$
to $1−x$

The absolute values are non-negative, but the actual values may be positive or negative.
So looking at the supports:
$$\begin{align}\{(x,y):0\leqslant \lvert x\rvert +\lvert y\rvert<1\}&=\{(x,y): 0\leqslant\lvert x\rvert<1~,~0\leqslant\lvert y\rvert\lt 1-\lvert x\rvert\} \\[1ex] &=\{(x,y):-1\lt x\lt 1~, \lvert x\rvert-1<y<1-\lvert x\rvert\}
\\[2ex] f_{X}(x) &= \mathbf 1_{-1\lt x\lt 1}\int_{\lvert x\rvert -1}^{1-\lvert x\rvert} 0.5\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=(1-\lvert x\rvert)\,\mathbf 1_{-1<x<1}\end{align}$$

You want to find
$$f(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$$
Note that for a fixed $x\in(-1,1)$, we have $f(x,y)=0$ if $|y|\geq 1-|x|$ which happens if $y\geq 1-|x|$ or $y\leq|x|-1$. Therefore,
$$f(x)=\int\limits_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$$
Hope this helps. :)
